# Excel Data Validation - Allowing multiple data types

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2010, excel-2007

I wish to set up some data validation on a cell in Microsoft Excel such that a user is able to enter either a date or "N/A". How might I go about this? I suspect it will require me utilising the "Custom" data validation option but I am uncertain.

Thank you kindly for any advice you are able to provide.

Comment: When you say "date", what permissible entries does that entail? Any that will be recognised (by your settings) as an acceptable date format?

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy. No other limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula for a custom Data Validation in cell `A1`:

```
=A1=IFERROR(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1)),"N/A")
```

This should to the trick. Let me know if you have any questions understanding the formula. Yet, the online help for all of these functions is pretty elaborate.

Comment: A value of, for example, 1, in A1 is accepted with that validation. As is any number x where 0<=x<=2958465.

Comment: @XORLX That's because dates are numbers. You'll have to change the number format to date on that cell in order to show the numbers as dates. Actually, if you wish you can enter into any cell today's date as 42,549 (though I guess there are not many people who'd know / want that). Data Validation can only check the value of a cell. Not it's format.

Comment: Of course, but the OP might wish to allow strictly dates only, i.e. have the format validated as well as content.

Comment: The number 42,549 is a date. Try it yourself and generate a date validation for any cell which accepts today's date and then enter 42,549 into that cell. Excel will accept the "date" even though it has been entered as a number. If the OP wants to make sure that dates are entered in a particular format (for example MM/DD/YYYY) then he/she will have to create something custom in a `UserForm`. To Excel a date is a number. Data Validation checks only the value. **NOT** the format in which it is entered. Anyway, if someone knows his dates, why not allow 42,549? ;)

Comment: Re "Data Validation can only check the value of a cell. Not it's format", not strictly true: we could, for example, employ the function CELL, with "format" as its first parameter, to that effect.

Comment: But then data validation would check the format of the cell and not it's content (which could be easily changed to show a date as a number). You just have to come to terms to the fact that **any** positive number within a certain range can be (to Excel) a date. It is only for the users' eyes that it is sometimes showing them as numbers and sometimes as dates. But that's only format. Not content.

Comment: I didn't say we use only the CELL function as part of the validation! A simple AND statement, e.g. incorporating your current construction, would be to the point. I don't know from where you have taken this idea that we cannot simultaneously check both content and format of a cell.

Comment: So, you want to fail the data entry if the format on a cell is changed to a number format instead of a date format? In that case, you better specify the error message as well as people will wonder why the cell no-longer accepts a valid date just because someone accidentally change the format on that cell to a number format. But still: this would check the visual representation only. The **value** being entered stays the same and gets checked by the condition I provided. Data validation cannot check if you enter 42,549 or 06/28/2016. They are both acceptable formats for the same value.

Comment: Good point, and apologies. It does indeed appear that validating cell format is too problematic. Best to use your solution combined perhaps with sheet protection to prevent changes to cell format.